# Collect list of Long from Double stream in Java 8

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I have the following code:

```
List<Long> list = new ArrayList<>();
list.add(4L);
list.add(92L);
list.add(100L);
List<Long> newList = list.stream().map(i -> i * 2.5)
                                  .mapToLong(Double::doubleToRawLongBits)
                                  .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

This code doesn't work and the compilation error is:

> method `collect` in interface `java.util.stream.LongStream` cannot be applied to given types;
>     
> required: `java.util.function.Supplier<R>,java.util.function.ObjLongConsumer<R>,java.util.function.BiConsumer<R,R>`
>     
> found: `java.util.stream.Collector<java.lang.Object,capture#1 of ?,java.util.List<java.lang.Object>>`
>     
> reason: cannot infer type-variable(s) `R`
>       (actual and formal argument lists differ in length)

I have tried many usages of Collectors but I still can't make it to work.
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What exactly do you think `Double.doubleToRawLongBits` does?  I don't think you know what it does...

Comment: It becomes DoubleStream after multiplication by 2.5.

Comment: @aldrael: incorrect.  It becomes a `Stream<Double>`, which is not the same thing.

Comment: @LouisWasserman could you tell me something more?

Answer (score 103, accepted):

[`mapToLong`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#mapToLong-java.util.function.ToLongFunction-) gives you a [`LongStream`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/LongStream.html) which is not able to be [`collect`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/LongStream.html#collect-java.util.function.Supplier-java.util.function.ObjLongConsumer-java.util.function.BiConsumer-)-ed by [`Collectors.toList`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#toList--).

This is because `LongStream` is

> A sequence of **primitive** long-valued elements

We can't have a `List<long>`, we need a `List<Long>`. Therefore to be able to collect them we first need to box these primitive `long`s into `Long` objects:

```
list.stream().map(i -> i * 2.5)
    .mapToLong(Double::doubleToRawLongBits)
    .boxed()                                //< I added this line
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

The [`boxed`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/LongStream.html#boxed--) method gives us a `Stream<Long>` which we're able to collect to a list.

Using [`map`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#map-java.util.function.Function-) rather than `mapToLong` will also work because that will result in a `Steam<Long>` where the values are automatically boxed:

```
list.stream().map(i -> i * 2.5)
    .map(Double::doubleToRawLongBits)
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: This is the best answer because it helps me, as a programmer who is new to Java 8, understand the "_why_". Thank you so much!

Answer (score 17):

This should compile if you use `map` instead of `mapToLong`.  (I'm not sure what you are trying to do with `doubleToRawLongBits` makes any sense, but that will at least compile.)

Comment: The point is I want to receive List<Long>, but using only map() and collect() I receive List<Double>.

Comment: @aldrael: no. Replacing `mapToLong` with `map` works fine. Just try.

Answer (score 6):

Not sure what you expect your results to look like but this generates a `List<Long>`.

```
public void test() {
    List<Long> list = new ArrayList<>();
    list.add(4L);
    list.add(92L);
    list.add(100L);
    List<Long> newList = list.stream()
            // Times 1.5.
            .map(i -> i * 2.5)
            // Grab the long bits.
            .mapToLong(Double::doubleToRawLongBits)
            // Box them.
            .boxed()
            // Make a list.
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
    System.out.println(newList);
}
```

Comment: `mapToLong(f).boxed()` is fully equivalent to `map(f)`.

Answer (score 1):

It’s not clear why you want to use `doubleToRawLongBits`. If your problem is that the multiplication with `2.5` produces `double` rather than `long`, you need a type cast to convert the value, as `doubleToRawLongBits` is not the canonical way of converting `double` to `long`. Instead, this method returns the IEEE 754 representation of the value which is only interesting in very special cases. Note that you can perform the conversion right inside the first `map` operation:

```
List<Long> list = new ArrayList<>();
list.add(4L);
list.add(92L);
list.add(100L);

List<Long> newList = list.stream().map(i -> (long)(i * 2.5))
                         .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

This even applies if you really want the IEEE 754 representation of `double` values:

```
List<Long> newList = list.stream().map(i -> Double.doubleToRawLongBits(i * 2.5))
                         .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

But note that if you have a temporary list whose type matching the result type, you may perform the operation in-place instead of creating two lists (and going through the `Stream` API):

```
List<Long> list = new ArrayList<>();
list.add(4L);
list.add(92L);
list.add(100L);
list.replaceAll(i -> (long)(i * 2.5));
```

again, the same applies even *if* you want IEEE 754 bits:

```
List<Long> list = new ArrayList<>();
list.add(4L);
list.add(92L);
list.add(100L);
list.replaceAll(i -> Double.doubleToRawLongBits(i * 2.5));
```

If you insist on using the `Stream` API, you may use the builder rather than an `ArrayList` for the source data:

```
Stream.Builder<Long> b = Stream.builder();
b.add(4L);
b.add(92L);
b.add(100L);
List<Long> newList = b.build().map(i -> (long)(i * 2.5))
                      .collect(Collectors.toList());
newList.forEach(System.out::println);
```

Answer (score 1):

The essence of this problem is that the return value of function `mapToLong` is `LongStream` interface. `LongStream` only has method

```
 <R> R collect(Supplier<R> supplier,
               ObjLongConsumer<R> accumulator,
               BiConsumer<R, R> combiner);
```

You may be want to use method

```
<R, A> R collect(Collector<? super T, A, R> collector);
```

You can find this method in [java.util.stream.Stream](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html) class.

the `LongStream` and `Stream` have no extend relationship.

Answer (score 0):

```
    HashMap<String, Map<String, Long>> map = new HashMap<>();

    List<Entry<String, Map<String, Long>>> sortedList = map
    .entrySet()
    .stream()
    .sorted((a, b) -> Long.compare(
                                   a.getValue().values().stream().mapToLong(l -> l).sum(),
                                   b.getValue().values().stream().mapToLong(l -> l).sum()))

    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```